# How to recover from bad configuration from Orchard's Multi Tenancy

Tags: orchardcms

I just installed the Multi Tenancy Module on my Orchard, I may have misconfiguration a new tenant by pointing the new tenant to use the host: localhost in the modules config for testing, and now I get a nasty error disabling the entire application.

*Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.ObjectDisposedException: Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed.*

I'm new to Orchard having just set up a 2008 server on the free tier on AWS today. I would like to know the simplest way to recover. Should I backup the Orchard Directory and the Database prior to fiddling in future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the settings files for each tenant. They are under `app_data/sites/TENANT`.